# Recurrence relation differencial equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to reconstruct a lemma.

We begin with a partition $0=t_0 < t_1 < ... < t_k < ... t_K = T$ and a recurrence relation where $y_{0}$ is any point in $
R$ and for some continuous and increasing function $w$ we have $|x(t)-x(s)|^{p} < w(t)-w(s)$ for all $0 \leq s \leq t \leq T$:

$y_{k+1} = y_{k} + f(y_{k})(x_{k+1}-x_{k}). $

The function $f$ is in $C^{\gamma}_{0}$ where $1\leq p < \gamma \leq 2$, that is, it has compact support and the derivative satisfies:

$|f'(t)-f'(s)| \leq A|t-s|^{\gamma-1}.$

The lemma states the following:

(A)There are positive numbers C,M, depending on $\gamma,p, w(T)-w(0), ||f||_{\infty} ,A$ such that

$|y_{l} - y_{k} - f(y_{k})(x_{l}-x_{k})| \leq M \cdot (w(t_l)-w(t_k))^{\gamma/p}. $
|

$|y_l-y_k| \leq C\cdot |w(t_l)-w(t_k)|^{1/p} $

(B) If $\hat{y_0}$ is another point in $R$ and $\hat{y_k}$ the value obtained after using $k$ times the recurrence relation then there is som $M' >0$ such that

$|y_k-\hat{y_k}\ \leq M' |y_0-\hat{y_0}|$

The proof of part A of this lemma is clear for me, but part B is not. The author says that if we derive the recurrence relation with respect to the initial value we get by using the chain rule (being $z_{k}$  the derivative of $y_{k}$ with respect to $y_{0}$)

$z_{k+1} = z_{k} + f'(y_{k})(z_{k})(x_{k+1}-x_{k}) $

This is also clear for me. The problem is that he says that this is a recurrence relation as the first one by substituting f by its derivative and then uses that to prove part B using part A. But since $z_{k}$ is there multiplying $f$, I do not see why he claims that it suffices to change $f$ by $f'$.

Then he claims that we obtain $|z_k| \leq constant \cdot (w(t_k)-w(0))^{1/p} \leq 1$. This is impossible to reconstruct for me.
From that we conclude part B of the lemma. Here is a link to the paper in case you want to check it. It is lemma 2.4

https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~sandy/rpathrev.pdf

Thank you for any help on this.

Comment: Could you please cite the relevant portion of the paper directly, Lemma 2.4 and related, best by writing it in mathjax? Your link is not permanent and the pdf has a size of 400kB, which is rather large for the small piece that is necessary here.

Comment: I decided  to rewrite the explanation since the paper has some theorems in between that are not necessary for this lemma.